# jqgrid asp.net webforms Server side SelectedRow property empty

Tags: asp.net, webforms, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to get this sample to work
[Get Selected Row (on server)](http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/selection/selectedrow/default.aspx)

but for me the SelectedRow property is always empty.

The only difference being that I am using the Page_load event to populate my grid.
When i press a button on my form, it does a postback, and repopulates the grid losing the row selection.

sample code:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack )
    {
        UserBusinessObject userBO = new UserBusinessObject();
        GRDUsers.DataSource = userBO.GetUsersbyProfileID(SessionFacade.Id);
        GRDUsers.DataBind();
    }


 protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(GRDUsers.SelectedRow))
     {
         lblError.Visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
         Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Manage/EditUserRoles.aspx?username={0}",GRDUsers.SelectedRow));

     }

}
```

I Have also noticed that on button click, my Page Load fires twice (1st time postback is true, 2nd time it is false) According to jqgrid posts this is intentional. but i think this might be causing my grief.

Comment: i have noted that this is only the case when i use a mastrpage, without it my server side selecting of the role is perfect

Comment: please provide the html murkup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with the guys at JQGrid, we have resolved the problem. It is a bug in their grid that has been fixed in v4.5.0.0

[see here for details](http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=2882)

i can confirm that this fixes the bug, and all is right with the world again

Answer (score 0):

You always must set the DataSource because is not saved on ViewState or anywhere else. So the code must be as:

```
UserBusinessObject userBO = new UserBusinessObject();
GRDUsers.DataSource = userBO.GetUsersbyProfileID(SessionFacade.Id);

if (!Page.IsPostBack )
{
    GRDUsers.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: If you are not calling databind then you don't need to set data source.

Comment: @MajoB You call the DataBind, but you must call it after the do what you do with the data, what I mean, on PageLoad + post back you avoid to make DataBind, you do that, onClick event (after the PageLoad) after you make your actions.

Comment: no, its not that. turns out the problem happens when i am working in a contentpage. if u take their sample app, and build it around a masterpage, the problem happend.